# DataTables constructing input data via Javascript dynamically does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to fill up a table dynamically. Following is my code. *dataTest* contains the final output of *dataSet* after the for loop. Using *dataTest* as the input for the table, the table works properly and it fills up. But, using *dataSet* throws out the error *DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0, column 1.*. I've tried looking at *https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4* about this, but am not able to figure out. *dataSet* and *dataTest* essentially have the same value. Why does *dataTest* work but *dataSet* doesn't?

```js
dataSet = "[";
for (prop = 0; prop < 26; prop++) 
{
   test = "['" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "','" + String(prop) + "'],";


    test = test.replace(/'/g, '"');
    // console.log(test);
    dataSet = dataSet.concat(test);
    // console.log(test.replace(/'/g, '"'));
    // test = "'" + String(array0[prop]) + "' : '"  + String(array1[prop]) + "'";
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
}
  end = "]";
  dataSet = dataSet.concat(end);
  console.log(dataSet);
  
var dataTest = [["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"],["1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],["3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3","3"],["4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"],["5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5","5"],["6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6"],["7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7","7"],["8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8","8"],["9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9","9"],["10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10","10"],["11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11","11"],["12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12","12"],["13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13","13"],["14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14","14"],["15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15","15"],["16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16","16"],["17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17","17"],["18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18","18"],["19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19","19"],["20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20","20"],["21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21","21"],["22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22","22"],["23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23","23"],["24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24","24"],["25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25","25"],]


  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
      data: dataSet,
      columns: [{
          title: "C1"
        },
        {
          title: "C2"
        },
        {
          title: "C3"
        },
        {
          title: "C4"
        },
        {
          title: "C5"
        },
        {
          title: "C6"
        },
        {
          title: "C7"
        },
        {
          title: "C8"
        },
        {
          title: "C9"
        },
        {
          title: "C10"
        },
        {
          title: "C11"
        },
        {
          title: "C12"
        },
        {
          title: "C13"
        },
        {
          title: "C14"
        },
        {
          title: "C15"
        },
        {
          title: "C16"
        },
        {
          title: "C17"
        },
        {
          title: "C18"
        },
        {
          title: "C19"
        },
        {
          title: "C20"
        },
      ]
      // columns: [
      //     { title: "Name" },
      //     { title: "Position" },
      //     { title: "Office" },
      //     { title: "Extn." },
      //     { title: "Start date" },
      //     { title: "Salary" }
      // ]
    });
  });
```

```html
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: with `dataSet `, are you creating a string that looks like an array?

Comment: Yes, I saw in the Javascript sourced data example here "https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html", and basically tried to replicate it using a for loop. I actually have data from 20 arrays that have actual data, passed from Python(Flask). They're too much to place here, so I simplified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your [doc link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) it seems you saw an array and decided to markup an array as a String (no good since data table expects an array and not a string that looks like an array). What you should have done is create the array using [JavaScript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

It worked with you variable `dataTest` because that is an actual array, and (again) not a string that looks like an array

Below is a example of how you can create the data properly for the data table.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [];
  for (var prop = 0; prop < 5; prop++) {
    var innerArray = [];
    for (var innerProp = 0; innerProp < 3; innerProp++) {
      innerArray.push(innerProp);
    }
    dataSet.push(innerArray);
  }
  //console.log(dataSet);

  $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [{
        title: "C1"
      },
      {
        title: "C2"
      },
      {
        title: "C3"
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables -->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Fantastic, this helped alot! Thanks!